# Manufacturer supported Webcams for Linux

Tags: linux

I have found sites with open source drivers (http://linux-uvc.berlios.de/) to support webcam use on Linux. However, does anyone know of any (external, not notebook built-in) that are officially supported by manufacturers as being compatible with Linux? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the application you're looking for, but IP cams with a built in web server would be OS neutral.  Admittedly it would probably cost more than a normal webcam.  Not quite the solution you asked for, but I figured I'd toss it out there since it would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Creative Labs have some support for them, in a [list of available drivers](http://connect.creativelabs.com/opensource/Lists/Webcams/AllItems.aspx). they don't make all the drivers themselves though, but its still nice to see the organisational effort.